# join two tables to modify the first table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables:

**Table A**

```
RowId   ProcessingDate  Flag
R1      P1              TRUE
R2      P2              TRUE
R1      P3              TRUE
R3      P4              TRUE
R2      P2              TRUE
R3      P5              TRUE
R1      P1              TRUE
```

where P3 > P1, P5 > P4

and **Table B**

```
RowId   ProcessingDate  Flag
R1      P3              FALSE
R2      P2              FALSE
R3      P5              FALSE
```

and I want to get the resultant table as:

```
RowId   ProcessingDate  Flag
R1      P1              TRUE
R2      P2              FALSE
R1      P3              FALSE
R3      P4              TRUE
R2      P2              TRUE
R3      P5              FALSE
R1      P1              TRUE
```

I tried to use left join but is not sure of which join key to use. I'm not very proficient in sql and want to know is it possible to get the resultant table without adding an extra column serial number??

Comment: What do you mean by "where P3 > P1" ? And why are your `RowId` values _not_ distinct? ...because that means it _isn't_ a Row-Identifier....

Comment: it means we're having multiple rowids and in table b, it contains the rowid with the latest processing date. That's why i was asking do we need a separate column for serial number as a unique identifier.

Comment: `P1` is not a date, what does `ProcessingDate` mean?

Comment: it can be a number or an epoch, why is p1 so concerning?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
update table_A
set table_A.Flag = table_B.Flag
from table_B 
join table_A on table_A.RowId = table_B.RowId AND table_A.ProcessingDate = 
table_B.ProcessingDate
```

Comment: These are datasets so i cannot directly use an sql query, right?

Comment: @anonymous change table_A and table_B to your table name, then you can use sql query to get the result you desire. Please be aware that update will change your Table A, you can create another table if you do not want to alter it

Comment: inputReconEntries.createOrReplaceTempView("table_A")
    otherReconEntries.createOrReplaceTempView("table_B")

    session.sql(s"""update table_A set table_A.isDuplicate = table_B.isDuplicate from table_B join table_A on table_A.rowId = table_B.rowId AND table_A.processingDate = table_B.processingDate""").as[ReconEntity]

Comment: @ Lara19, I tried this, but getting the error - org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException

Comment: @anonymous Please check it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/wgJmAhul, I see no error from my SQL